# how to send Codable json data to table view or collection view controller in swift

Tags: arrays, json, struct, view, codable

First of all, I am beginner in iOS or swift development and want to be a swift developer.
Please help me to solve this type of problem and become a good developer. 
I want to set parsing jsondata to viewcontroller or tableview controller.
I can parsing json data and see in console but can't set that data to vc or tableview controller.
here my sample json data

```
[
  {
    "genre_id": "",
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "slug": "",
    "url": "",
    "videos": [
       {
         "videos_id": "",
         "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "slug": "",
        "release": "",
        "is_tvseries": "",
        "runtime": "",
        "video_quality": "",
        "thumbnail_url": "",
        "poster_url": ""
      },
      {
        "videos_id": "",
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "slug": "",
        "release": "",
        "is_tvseries": "",
        "runtime": " ",
        "video_quality": "",
        "thumbnail_url": "",
        "poster_url": ""
      }
    ]
    }, 
    {
    "genre_id": "",
    "name": "",
    "description": " ",
    "slug": "",
    "url": "",
    "videos": [
      {
        "videos_id": "",
        "title": " ",
        "description": "",
        "slug": "",
        "release": "",
        "is_tvseries": "",
        "runtime": "",
        "video_quality": "",
        "thumbnail_url": "",
        "poster_url": ""
      },
      {
        "videos_id": "",
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "slug": "",
        "release": "",
        "is_tvseries": "",
        "runtime": "",
        "video_quality": "",
        "thumbnail_url": "",
        "poster_url": ""
      } 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make more effort on researching on your problem but here you can read this [blog](https://blog.usejournal.com/json-data-on-tableview-using-swiftyjson-and-alamofire-9b25c9a206e8) .

PS: I can't make a comment yet